# Bootstrap custom popover doesn't appear on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, popover

Actually i'm tying to show a custom popover after the user press on an anchor then he can choose an item and i'd do some server operations after it.

The issue is that after i press the first time on the anchor nothing happen but if i press again the pooper will be shown.

Then i would hide the popover if the user press on the background.

Here is the function which i hire from the anchor

```
<script>
    function pop(id) {
        $("#" + id).popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $('#popover-content').html();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

While here is the code of the popover that i'm trying to show

```
 <li id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
            <a href="#" class="badge badge-primary">CHIUSO</a>
            <a href="#" class="badge badge-success">RISOLTO</a>
            <a href="#" class="badge badge-warning">IN ATTESA</a>
            <a href="#" class="badge badge-danger">SCADUTO</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: How do you execute the `pop(id)` function? This function just registers the popover on the given element, but does not open it.

Comment: @Sebastian actually i set on the anchor "onclick(this.id);" in the dynamically created anchor

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this jQuery script?

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

As shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover&stacked=h).

Tell us if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `$().popover({...})` method registers the popover but does not show it yet. So the first exectuion of your `pop(id)` function will just register the popover on the element.

When you want to show the popover on click you have to also programmatically show it after you register it so your function should look like this.

```
function pop(id) {
    // register the popover
    $("#" + id).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
    });

    // show the popover
    $("#" + id).popover('show');
}
```